# How to make UIProgressView standard rectangle, without rounded corners?

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

The UIProgressView by default has `rounded corners`.

**How can I get rid of those `rounded corners`?** I wish to have a `standard rectangle view`.

I have tried `progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;`, but no use.

Comment: I left an edit for this question. The left edge of the progress tint area has squared off corners, but the right edge of the track area has rounded corners.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to create non rounded corner UIProgressView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917974/how-to-create-non-rounded-corner-uiprogressview-in-ios-using-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subclass `UIProgressView` and override `drawRect`.

**EDIT 08/31/2016:**

[Here was a tutorial](http://goto11.net/skinning-a-uiprogressview-with-drawrect-and-images/) 
;-)

Come on: This one is from 2012, the Question is closed, iOS had a few updates and so had the SDK and the ProgressView API, we're (hopefully) using swift now ... and yes: The link is broken. So, feel free to downvote this one, but ask yourself, if a non-broken link would really solve your problem.

Comment: Can I directly control the height and weight of it after I subclass as indicated in the tutorial? I mean I can use `progressView.frame = ...`?

Comment: Yes. UIProgressView is a subclass of UIView, so you can.

Comment: @Mundi I have tried, but the no use

Comment: @Jackson Tale didn't test the tutorial code, but as it shows a lot of happy comments, it should work. And it says "[...]you can make it any size you want[...]". So what exactly does not work in you app?

Comment: @KaiHuppmann, link is not available.

Comment: down voted for answering with just a link, which happens to be dead