# How to create non rounded corner UIProgressView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I have subclassed UIProgressView as:

```
import UIKit

class MyProgressView: UIProgressView {

    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(size.width, 6)
    }
}
```

and I am using it as:

```
let progress = MyProgressView()

progress.progress = 0.33
progress.layer.cornerRadius = 0
progress.tintColor = .white
progress.trackTintColor = UIColor.white.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
navigationItem.titleView = progress
```

it's working fine, but it has rounded corners like below

[image: progress view with rounded corners]

I want it to be non rounded corner. How can I do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simply change the [`progressViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview/1619845-progressviewstyle) to `UIProgressView.Style.bar`, Default is `UIProgressView.Style.default`.

**Swift 3.0 and above**

```
self.progressViewStyle = .bar /* default is .default */
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
self.progressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyle.Bar
```

Comment: you can override init method or can call after creating object of  MyProgressView. 
for e.g let progressView = MyProgressView() 
               progressView.progressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyle.Bar

Comment: and if you   are just creating a subclass for this(for Bar). then you shouldn't  create . you can do it by storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I am using Xib's